# How to get distinct rows from mongo including matching parent rows

Tags: mongodb

The schema is the following:

```
const CitySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        region: {type: String, required: true},
        region_id: {type: Number, required: true},
    }
);
```

After populating the collection I have this:

```
{ "region" : "Texas", "region_id" : 1, "name" : "Houston"}
{ "region" : "Texas", "region_id" : 1, "name" : "Dallas"}
{ "region" : "California", "region_id" : 2, "name" : "Los Angeles"}
{ "region" : "California", "region_id" : 2, "name" : "San Francisco"}
{ "region" : "Pennysylvania", "region_id" : 3, "name" : "Philadelphia"}
{ "region" : "Pennysylvania", "region_id" : 3, "name" : "Pittsburgh"}
```

What I need is a structure that looks like this:

```
{ "region" : "California", "region_id" : 2, "cities" : ["San Francisco", "Los Angeles"]}
{ "region" : "Pennysylvania", "region_id" : 3, "cities" : ["Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh"]}
{ "region" : "Texas", "region_id" : 1, "cities" : ["Houston", "Dallas"]}
```

Right now I first run a single query to obtain all the regions in a distinct way:

```
db.cities.aggregate({ $group: { _id: { region: "$region", region_id: "$region_id" } } }, { "$sort" : { '_id.region': 1 }});
```

And then the plan is to loop among the regions and then fetch cities. But this sounds a bit ineffective. is there a way to get all the data in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `region_id`, get first `region` using `$first`, and push `cities` using `$push`
- `$sort` by `region` in ascending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$region_id",
      region: { $first: "$region" },
      cities: { $push: "$name" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { region: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_P-NgH8wIsb)